# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) iOS application

Tags: ios

I am trying to make a sense out of following crash which is reported by Crashlytics

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000001a20c7fbf81
VM Region Info: 0x1a20c7fbf81 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1784231739266  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [10401]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000104293578 0x103fe4000 + 2815352
1   MyApp                           0x00000001014770f4 objectdestroy.150Tm + 40
2   MyApp                           0x00000001014770f4 objectdestroy.150Tm + 40
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000104293584 0x103fe4000 + 2815364
4   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000001d3993a44 _Block_release + 152
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d3937484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d38e39ec _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d3e8d1bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d3e88084 __CFRunLoopRun + 1964
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d3e875b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001d60fb584 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000002000e3558 UIApplicationMain + 212
12  MyApp                           0x0000000100d31160 main + 37216 (AppDelegate.swift:16)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001d3947b94 start + 4
```

We started seeing this crash after we upgraded to Xcode 10, not sure if its related to SDK. 
I tried to symbolicate the symbols using `atos` but that doesn't lead anywhere. The only bright side is that we can repro the crash on a `release` build with following steps

1. Launch the app and Log In
2. Turn Wifi off (no internet connection on the device)
3. Log out

The application would crash 1 out of every 3-5 tries

Looking at the crash it seems that the app is trying to access invalid memory address (most likely trying to access an object after it was released) but cannot narrow it down

Does any know how to use the address offset shown in following lines, can I convert the integer offset to hex and add it to `0x103fe4000`?

```
 0   libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000104293578 0x103fe4000 + 2815352
 3   libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000104293584 0x103fe4000 + 2815364
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: “the app is trying to access invalid memory address (most likely trying to access an object after it was released) but cannot narrow it down” Turn on Zombies?

Comment: You really need to symbolicate that crash log to determine the MyApp file and line being referenced in frames 1 and 2. An unsymbolicated crash log is marginally useful. If this crashes 1 out of 3-5 times, can you reproduce it with a debug build tethered to Xcode? That would be the best scenario. If not, create a build and corresponding dsym that you can use to get symbolicated crash logs. Scanning the info in this one, I'd expect that there might be a previously released object being deallocated (or a bad object reference attempting to be deallocated). Also may be related to a block/closure.